# Why does my JSF + Spring web application output JSF source code instead of interpreted HTML page?

Tags: spring, web-applications, xhtml, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm new to both JSF and Spring Framework and I'm trying to figure out how to make them work together.
My current problem is that application outputs my JSF files without interpreting them. 
Here are some snippets of my code which I believe might be relevant:

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="login.htm">loginController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
      p:suffix=".xhtml" />

<bean name="loginController" class="controller.LoginController" />
```

**loginController**

```
public class LoginController extends MultiActionController {
 public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("LOGIN");
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

**WEB-INF/pages/login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>#{message.log}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{message.username}" for="userName">
            <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{User.name}" />
        </h:outputLabel>            
        <h:commandButton value="#{message.loggin}" action="#{User.login}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Any ideas where the problem might be? Does this code make any sense at all? I'm well aware of fact, that probably completely sucks and I'll be glad to here WHY it sucks and how to make it better. Thanks :)

EDIT: I'm adding piece of code which seems to be the root of the problem and which I (of course) didn't include in the original question:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url-pattern of Faces Servlet had to be changed to *.xhtml in order to work properly.

Comment: PS: J2EE is dead for almost 4 years. It's called Java EE since release of Java EE 5.0. Choose tags carefully ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JSF tags are not been parsed, then it simply means that the request URL did not match the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`. It is namely responsible for all that JSF happenings. You need to verify if the request URL matches the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`. If it is for example `*.jsf`, then you need to invoke it by `http://example.com/context/page.jsf` and thus not by `http://example.com/context/page.xhtml`.

I am however not sure how Spring fits in the picture since I don't use it, but to get JSF to work you really need to pass the request through the `FacesServlet` first, not through some Spring controller. Spring should do its job *thereafter*.

Comment: I'm trying to change web.xml as you said and I'm getting these errors:
WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/PodleRose2] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
What does that mean?

Comment: Geez... now it works but I'm even more frustrated than I was before because I'm 98% sure I tried the same setting at least 3x before and it didn't work :-O
Is that Netbeans or is this standard behaviour in field of Java web applications? :-D

Comment: The former exception will indeed be thrown when you don't pass the request through the `FacesServlet`. It's the one responsible for creating the `FacesContext`. The JSF components in the XHTML page are complaining about that since they require the `FacesContext` to function properly. Glad that you got it working anyway :)

Comment: Anyway.. thanks for help, it seems to do what I expect it to do (for a change). Now I'm can hopefully get to my original application-scope-bean problem from yesterday :)